# 3D Touch peek and touches

Tags: ios, uikit, 3dtouch

I'm trying to implement the peek and pop actions from UIKit.
I noticed that whenever I am in the peek view, there is no way for my view controller to receive touches. This is problematic because I plan to enable user interaction in this view controller.
Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Peek view purpose is to preview content of view controller. So it's clear, that preview is for previewing content, not interacting with it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer when you peek, you cannot get touch events for that view controller but you can perform certain actions by adding **previewActionItems**.